Why does my cat have scabs on the webbing between her toes?
My 11 year old Maine Coon mix has been having these scabs on the webbing part of her toes. I unfortunately can’t provide a picture because she won’t let me.I know a few weeks ago we had fleas but we gave them all medicine (i have 4 other pets,3 cats and one dog) so could it be that?

It's simply impossible for us to know why x happened, but fleas do pierce the skin to drink blood and they prefer thin, tender skin,, so it's certainly possible that these scabs were caused by them.
